# Can't change ssh port (Trusty 14.04)

Tags: ssh, openssh

I've been trying to change my ssh port without success and none of the suggestions I've found did the trick for me.

I'm on Trusty 14.04 at Rackspace (upgraded from Precise). This is the sequence of steps I've taken to change the ssh port

I just can't seem to change the Port ssh is listening on. 
Changed sshd_config

```
AllowUsers abc
Port 9603
```

Reloaded sshd

```
sudo /etc/init.d/ssh restart
```

Opened the firewall

```
sudo ufw enable
sudo ufw allow 9603
sudo ufw reload
```

But I always get connection refused when I try to connect.

```
ssh abc@1.2.3.4 -p 9603
```

When I run netstat -an | grep "LISTEN ", I get

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

For some reason, it looks like ssh is not changing ports despite my changes. Any suggestions? I have no moves left

Comment: Just to verify, you are editing the file at `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, right? Also, is there any difference if you try `sudo service ssh restart`?

Comment: Post your entire sshd_config on a pastebin for review.

Comment: You're right! sudo service ssh restart did the trick! Thanks. If you "answer" the question, I'll give you the appropriate kudos